# "Try two for two"

Tags: expressions

Couple of times I've heard that expression. As I see it, it's used when someone gives something a second attempt.

> Let's see how my luck goes – shall I try two for two?

A. What does "two for two" mean? Is it "two *tries* for two *wins*"? (is that a right way to rephrase it?)

B. Does this (necessarily) mean the first attempt was successful?

Comment: The expression (at least as I've heard it) is "shall I try for two for two?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with Question B:

**B. Does this (necessarily) mean the first attempt was successful?**

Yes, it does. The expression ***x for y*** (where x and y are generally relatively small integers), means ***x successes, out of y attempts***. So:

> He was two for three against Boston

means he had two successes in three attempts. (The meaning is context dependent: in basketball, we might be talking about free throws; in baseball, we might be talking about at bats. If Boston is the last name of a politician, we could be talking about the results of three mayoral elections, where Mr. Boston won once.)

So, in the case of:

> Let's see how my luck goes – shall I try two for two?

If the first attempt was unsuccessful, the best the speaker could try for is *one for two*. Hence, the first attempt must have been successful. The speaker is now *1 for 1*, not *0 for 1* ("0 for 1" is usually pronounced as "oh for one," at least in the U.S.).

---

**A. What does "two for two" mean? Is it a "two tries for two wins"? (is that a right way to rephrase it?)**

In this context, "two for two" can be rephrased as "two wins in two attempts" (or "two wins *out of* two attempts").

I would not say, "Two tries for two wins." That sounds like something you'd say before an event, when you are going to get two tries.